# Accessing shared folders on repeater routers

Tags: wireless-networking, router, shared-folders, wireless-bridge

[image]

As it shown on my network diagram here, both computers can access the internet without any problem. The problem is my Laptop can't access shared folders on my PC and vice versa. If I connect both computers on the same router I can access shared folders without a problem. The goal is to have a network without cables.

My setup is two Routers TP-Link 3420 v5 running OpenWrt 18.06.1, one PC and one Laptop I have disabled firewall on both computers.

Comment: Router1's LAN cable, in what port on Router 2 is it connected? If you use WAN, then it won't work. If you use LAN1-4, then it should work. This will turn router2 into a switch + AP and disables the router part. Also, The Default Gateway should be set to 192.168.1.1 on the laptop.

Comment: Thank you for your input. According to your idea, it should definitely work but the goal is to have a network without cables.

Comment: A router is not a repeater, and that's why its not working. You can either place a wire to router 2 and make it work, or replace router 2 with a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to accomplish the job with a guide from the official OpenWRT site. I carefully follow this guide https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/relay_configuration